# How to remove the RESTORE (D:) partition?

Tags: windows

I recently made a dual partition on my laptop for Windows + Mint, and Mint being the secondary boot. I've realised windows created a new partition on my disk `RESTORE (D:)` and the content inside is `D:\Recovery\RecoveryImage/ASUS.swm` file that is ~16.5GB big. Is it safe to remove it? If yes how? I can't seem to remove it from Disk Mangement. [This is what I get when right clicking on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGdKl.png).

Comment: no, you should not remove it. If things go wrong or you want to sell the laptop to someone else for example, this partition can be used to get the laptop back in a working state. 16gb is not worth worrying about.

Comment: No, it’s not safe.

Answer (score 0):

The 16.5 GB partition contains the computer manufacturer
factory recovery partition. This is where images are kept which will
restore your computer to factory settings.

Removing this partition will get you a small amount of disk space,
at the cost of losing a recovery mechanism that might be required
in case of a catastrophic failure.

In the comments it was also remarked that restoring the computer to
factory setting could be useful when you decide to sell the computer
or give it away.